# Public key denied when fetching from Bitbucket in Ansbile with Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, ssh, ansible, ssh-agent

#### What I am trying to do:

I have an Ansible script which does a git clone from Bitbucket, and I'm running that script from jenkins via the Ansible plugin.

The route:

```
Jenkins server ---(ansible)---> App server ----(git)---> bitbucket.org
```

I'm trying to connect to the repo on Bitbucket from the App server, using the ssh private key on the Jenkins server, which should be achievable with the help of `ssh-agent`.

#### What's going wrong:

The Ansible script fails connecting to Bitbucket with `Public key denied`.

#### What I have checked:

1. The public key on Jenkins has been added to deploy keys list and it do works without permission problems.
2. `ssh-agent` is running on the jenkins node and the private key on jenkins has been added.
3. `AllowFowardAgent` has been set to `yes` on the server.
4. The ansible plugin for jenkins copies the private key to `/tmp` and use it when running playbooks. It's not the same file path to what I have `ssh-add`-ed, but I don't think that's causing the problem.

#### The Jenkins code

Before running the Ansible task I have the below shell script run first:

```
eval `ssh-agent -s`
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa

cat >~/.ssh/config <<EOL
Host *
    ForwardAgent    yes
EOL

cat ~/.ssh/config

git clone git@bitbucket.org:myuser/myrepo.git
```

#### The Ansible code

My playbook:

```
- name: check SSH_AUTH_SOCK
  shell: echo "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK"

- name: check ssh-agent forwarding
  shell: ssh -T git@bitbucket.org
```

My `ansible.cfg`:

```
[ssh_connection]
ssh_args = -o ForwardAgent=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s
```

#### The output

In my Ansible script I can see that `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` is set:

```
11:29:04 changed: [testserver] => {"changed": true, "cmd": "echo \"$SSH_AUTH_SOCK\"", "delta": "0:00:00.007881", "end": "2016-09-06 11:29:04.576963", "invocation": {"module_args": {"_raw_params": "echo \"$SSH_AUTH_SOCK\"", "_uses_shell": true, "chdir": null, "creates": null, "executable": null, "removes": null, "warn": true}, "module_name": "command"}, "rc": 0, "start": "2016-09-06 11:29:04.569082", "stderr": "", "stdout": "/tmp/ssh-WnmHgtzMBS/agent.13630", "stdout_lines": ["/tmp/ssh-WnmHgtzMBS/agent.13630"], "warnings": []}
```

But `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org` fails:

```
11:29:09 fatal: [testserver]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "ssh -T git@bitbucket.org", "delta": "0:00:05.009720", "end": "2016-09-06 11:29:09.879430", "failed": true, "invocation": {"module_args": {"_raw_params": "ssh -T git@bitbucket.org", "_uses_shell": true, "chdir": null, "creates": null, "executable": null, "removes": null, "warn": true}, "module_name": "command"}, "rc": 255, "start": "2016-09-06 11:29:04.869710", "stderr": "Error reading response length from authentication socket.\r\nPermission denied (publickey).", "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": [], "warnings": []}
```

Comment: Does `ssh-add -L` show the forwarded public key (next to `check SSH_AUTH_SOCK` task)?

Comment: @techraf Weirdly, it says `Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.`

Comment: @techraf `AllowForwardingAgent` has been set to yes in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. (which defaults to yes) and I can execute the same ansible script from my laptop, but not from the jenkins machine. It seems that the ssh-agent gets lost after ansible-playbook starts running (SSH_AUTH_SOCK is set in the App server but not in the Jenkins server), but still don't know why.

Comment: Kinda found the solution: Use the ssh-agent plugin for jenkins, instead of running `ssh-agent` and `ssh-add` in the shell script. But still don't know why the shell script way can go wrong.

Comment: I guess if you ran Ansible from the same script you called `eval` it would work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you execute `ssh-agent -s` it outputs a series of environment variables which are required for agent forwarding feature of SSH, for example:

```
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/var/folders/nw/2vnhg_gj77v_cyfv0p1vdfj80000gn/T//ssh-alCh0yLKdoci/agent.53532; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK; SSH_AGENT_PID=53533; export SSH_AGENT_PID; echo Agent pid 53533;
```

When you run it through `eval` these commands get executed in the current shell session and you can see the output of the last one (`echo`):

```
Agent pid 53533
```

The environment variables however are set for the current process and subprocesses. If you call Ansible playbook from a different process, they won't be seen.

As you already figured out, the SSH Agent Plugin for Jenkins takes care so that other processes (like Ansible plugin) will inherit these environment variables.

Comment: I assumed jenkins runs build scripts in the same session, which seems to be wrong. Thanks!

Comment: It probably runs in the same session, but spawns separate processes for tasks (the script and Ansible are siblings). Otherwise it would have to make the execution cascading (one process calls the other at the end) and that would be quite an effort.